# How can I define class using multiple generic?

Tags: java, generics

I want to create object like belows :

```
private MyHashTable<AVLtree<TreeData>, TreeData> hashTable = new MyHashTable<>();
```

`AVLtree` and `TreeData` is what I defined, not java built in class.
But, I have no idea how to define MyHashTable class using generic.
What I can think about is 
    `public class MyHashTable<S<T>,T>`   but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare like this

```
public class MyObject<T> {
}

public class MyHashTable<S extends MyObject<T>, T> {
}
```

In this case you can use

```
public class MyHashTable<S extends AVLTree<T>, T> {
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Give me your source code. T cant be resolve in your function or i your class header.